# Can Slick update database schemas?

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

I'm using Slick 2.1.0 with Scala to do insertions and queries into a database. However, I might be using it for table creation as well, with a possible need to update the table's schemas. Can schema updates like this be done with Slick, or can it only do table creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say no, the fact that it maps tables and queries to entities makes it static, if you alter a table you would need to also modify your code to represent the table and you have to do it manually, the best that slick can do is generate the schema on demand using the schema generator tool, also I never saw something like this on the documentation.

If you use Play! there are some alternatives like using [evolutions](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Evolutions), but as far as I know this is as far as it can get.